# Multiple line spinner for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spinner

Is it possible to have a muti-line status spinner for python with something like yaspin or equiv?

For example, I would like to use multiprocessing and show the output of n number of items at one time:

```
⌛ Loading Version 1
✔️  Completed Version 8
⌛ Starting Version 3
✘  Task Version 77 failed 
⌛ Running Something Different
```

In the sample above, i am just showing an hourglass, checkmark, etc. to indicate running/success/error.

Comment: The example includes non-ASCII icons, where would you expect to show the spinners? On the console with regular characters, or on some other output?

Comment: So far the only 2 I have tried allow you to include non-ASCII, but thats not a real requirement, i was using above as sample indicators of running/finished.

Comment: If you require that these lines appear directly below the command, at any position on the screen, you may be in for a bit of work. If you don't mind the screen clearing first, you should look at `curses`.

Answer (score 3):

[Halo](https://github.com/manrajgrover/halo) is going to support this exact use case as soon as [this PR](https://github.com/manrajgrover/halo/pull/155) gets approved.

[image: Multiple spinners example GIF]

---

**EDIT**

If you want to use this feature straight away, (as of today) this is the fork you are looking for: [frostming/halo:multiple-spinners](https://github.com/frostming/halo/tree/multiple-spinners)

For instance, to use it as a dependency with `poetry`:

```
halo = { git = "https://github.com/frostming/halo.git", branch = "multiple-spinners" }
```

Comment: unfortunately, looks like that PR is in purgatory lol

Comment: @n1c9 You are right, that PR is kind of stale atm. I updated the answer for whoever find it and look for a (temporary) workaround.